# hosts.deny not working

Tags: security, iptables, denyhosts

Currently I am watching the live auth.log and someone is continuously trying the brute force attack for 10 hours.

Its my local server so no need to worry but I want to test.

I have installed denyhosts.

There is already an entry for that IP address in hosts.deny. But still he is trying the attacks from same IP. System is not blocking that.

Firstly I don't know how did that IP address get entered in that file. I didn't enter it, is there any other system script which can do that.

hosts.deny is

```
sshd: 120.195.108.22
sshd: 95.130.12.64
```

hosts.allow

```
ALL:ALL
sshd: ALL
```

Is there any iptable setting that can override the host.deny file

Comment: I will go home today and will make that 100% , your happiness is more important to me. You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hosts.allow` can override `hosts.deny`. Remove those entries from `hosts.allow`. See the `hosts_access(5)` man page for details.

Comment: but i want to accept ALL Connections expect from those in hosts.deny. should i empty my hosts.allow file

Comment: Yes. Anything not in `hosts.deny` will be allowed by default.